# raft: some questions about read only queries

Tags: raft

In the raft's thesis document chapter 6.4, it gives steps to bypass the Raft log for read-only queries and still preserve linearizability:

> 1. If the leader has not yet marked an entry from its current term committed, it waits until it has done so. The Leader Completeness
>      Property guarantees that a leader has all committed entries, but at
>      the start of its term, it may not know which those are. To find out,
>      it needs to commit an entry from its term. Raft handles this by having
>      each leader commit a blank no-op entry into the log at the start of
>      its term. As soon as this no-op entry is committed, the leader’s
>      commit index will be at least as large as any other servers’ during
>      its term.
> 2. The leader saves its current commit index in a local variable readIndex. This will be used as a lower bound for the version of the
>      state that the query operates against.
> 3. The leader needs to make sure it hasn’t been superseded by a newer leader of which it is unaware. It issues a new round of heartbeats and
>      waits for their acknowledgments from a majority of the cluster. Once
>      these acknowledgments are received, the leader knows that there could
>      not have existed a leader for a greater term at the moment it sent the
>      heartbeats. Thus, the readIndex was, at the time, the largest commit
>      index ever seen by any server in the cluster.
> 4. The leader waits for its state machine to advance at least as far as the readIndex; this is current enough to satisfy linearizability.
> 5. Finally, the leader issues the query against its state machine and replies to the client with the results.

My questions:

a) for step 1, is it only for case at the time of the leader is just elected? Because only new leader has no entry committed for current term. And since the no-op entry is necessary to find out the current committed entries, then this step in fact is always needed upon election done, but not only specific to read-only query? In other words, normally, when the leader is active for a while, it must has entries committed for its term (including the no-op entry).

b) for step 3, does it mean as long as leader needs to serve read only query, then one extra heartbeat would be sent, regardless of current outstanding heartbeat (sent but no major responses received yet) or the next scheduled heartbeat?

c) for step 4, is it only for followers (for cases where followers help offload the processing of read-only queries)? Because on leader, committed index already means it was applied to local state machine.

All in all, normally, the leader (active for a while) only needs to do step 3 and step 5, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**a**: This is indeed only the case when the leader is first elected. In practice, when a read-only query is received, you check whether an entry has been committed from the leader's current term and queue or reject the query if not.

**b**: In practice, most implementations batch read-only queries for more efficiency. You don't need to send many concurrent heartbeats. If a heartbeat is outstanding, the leader can enqueue any new reads to be evaluated after that heartbeat is completed. Once a heartbeat is completed, if any additional queries are enqueued then the leader starts another heartbeat. This has the effect of batching linearizable read-only queries for better efficiency.

**c**: It is *not* true that the leader's `lastApplied` index (the index of its state machine) is always equivalent to its `commitIndex`. Indeed, this is why there *is* a `lastApplied` index in Raft in the first place. Leaders do not necessarily have to synchronously apply an index at the same time as committing that index. This is really implementation specific. In practice, Raft implementations usually apply entries in a different thread. So, an entry can be committed and then enqueued for application to the state machine. Some implementations put entries on a queue to be applied to the state machine and allow the state machine to *pull* entries from that queue to be applied at the state machine's own pace, so when an entry may be applied is unspecified. It's just critical that a read-only query be applied after the last command committed by the leader.

Also, you ask if this only applies to followers. Linearizable queries can only be evaluated through the leader. I suppose there's some algorithm with which you could do linearizable reads on followers, but it would be inefficient. Followers can only maintain sequential consistency for queries. In that case, servers respond to client operations with the index of the state machine when the operation was evaluated. Clients send their last received index with each operation, and when a server receives an operation, it uses the same algorithm to ensure that its state machine's `lastApplied` index is at least as great as the client's index. This is necessary to ensure that the client does not see state go back in time when switching servers.

There are some other complexities to read-only queries beyond what's described in the Raft literature if you want to support FIFO consistency for concurrent operations from a single client. Some of these are described in Copycat's [architecture documentation](http://atomix.io/copycat/docs/).

Comment: If the leader does step 3 of exchanging heartbeat, is step 1 of committing no-op still required? Exchanging heartbeats already help the leader to find `commitIndex`, right?